# ocultar un div con javascript en materialize css

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

Quiero saber como hacer para mostrar un div que esta oculto por la clase "hide" en materialize. Si yo ejecuto de esta forma Id_div.className -= "hide"; funciona perfectamente pero si uso la variable como abajo la funcion deja de funcionar mostrando el mensaje de undefined hide.

```
function mostrar(Id_div){
 var x=Id_div;
 x.className -= "hide";
}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿por qué estás usando el `-=`? Para que ya no considere como oculto simplemente tienes que ponerle una cadena vacía, así Materialize va a reconocer que ya no hay que ocultarlo.

Comment: por que la clase del div es class="hide" al usar -= class queda como class="" en pocas palabras le quita

Comment: Si tienes: `var className = 'hide'; className -= 'hide'; console.log(className);` el resultado sería: `NaN`. No creo que sea eso lo que quieres lograr. Si estás usando jQuery usa un `removeClass()`, si lo haces con JavaScript simplemente conviértelo a una cadena vacía: `x.className = ''`

Comment: <div id="Id_div" class="hide">
            <p>Aqui hay un texto oculto</p>
  </div>  al usar ese comando se muestra el texto

Comment: Ese no es el problema. El problema es que jquery no acepta x.className -= "hide"; solo acepta Id_div.className -= "hide"; funciona con el id en concreto no con una variable

Comment: ¿Qué tal si lo explicas mejor en tu pregunta y de paso actualizas el código para mostrar de qué manera estás llamando a tu función `mostrar`?